# Python - How to Create a Genealogical Tree

Tags: python, recursion, anytree

I would like to develop a Genealogy Tree with Python.

I'm using the Django Framework 2.1.

I have a model called "Animal":

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField( null=True)
    id_mother = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Does exists in Python a way to recursively generate a tree from this object? I tried the AnyTree but I'm just getting one result, **it only shows the current animal**, but it doesn't get his mother, neither grandmother.

I'm trying to use this code with anytree to generate the tree:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, AsciiStyle

    def generate_tree(beginningId):
        if isinstance(beginningId, int):
            animal = Animal.objects.get(pk=beginningId)
        else:
            animal = Animal.objects.get(pk=beginningId.id)

        animalNode = Node(animal)

        if animal.id_mother is not None:
            generate_tree(animal.id_mother).parent = animalNode

        return animalNode
```

View:

```
def show_tree(request):
tree = generate_tree(221)
nt = RenderTree(tree, style=AsciiStyle())

print(nt)

return render(
    request, 
    'agr/reports/tree.html', 
    {
        'tree': tree, 
        'page_title': page_title
    }
)
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ – it implements various tree structures effectively in the database. If all you have is a `parent`/`mother` foreign key, querying a deep structure will be slow (and/or require a recursive CTE).

Comment: As an additional aside, the names of your `ForeignKey` columns should not contain `id`: the idiom is just `mother = models.ForeignKey(...)`, so Django constructs a `mother_id` column in the database behind the scenes.

Comment: Also: unless you want to change the type of your primary key, no need to specify it either.